# How to override theme_file_widget?

Tags: 7, theming

Is there any method to override this function `theme_file_widget`.

I tried to to do the following in my module.

`function mymodule_file_widget($variables)`

and also in my theme

`function mytheme_file_widget($variables)`

but did not work. I cleared the cache also. Is there any method to override this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to override the theme function is:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['file_widget']['function'] = 'mymodule_file_widget';
}

function mymodule_file_widget($variables) {
 //your code
}
```